# To combine values of two dropdownlist and pass the value to a hidden field using javascript

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form name="payment_info" id="payment_info" action="https://www.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchant/process.do" method="post" >
    <div class="check_form_cover">
        <div class="check_form_txt fleft">Account Number:</div>
        <div class="check_form_field fleft"><input name="ssl_card_number" id="ssl_card_number"  type="text" class="check_form_field1" /></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="check_form_cover">
        <div class="check_form_txt fleft">Expiry Date:</div>
        <div class="check_form_field fleft"><select name="month" id="month" onchange="setOptions(document.payment_info.month.value);">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="1">Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
            <option value="4">Apr</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">Jun</option>
            <option value="7">Jul</option>
            <option value="8">Aug</option>
            <option value="9">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>

        <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="ssl_show_form" id="ssl_show_form" value="TRUE">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_show_form" id="ssl_show_form" value="TRUE">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_amount" id="ssl_amount" value="'.$total.'">
<input type="hidden" name="ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator" id="ssl_cvv2cvc2_indicator" value="Present">
<div class="check_form_cover">
    <div class="check_form_txt fleft">CVV Number:</div>
    <div class="check_form_field fleft"><input name="ssl_cvv2cvc2" id="ssl_cvv2cvc2"  type="text" class="check_form_field1" /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="check_form_cover">
    <div class="check_form_txt fleft"></div>
    <div class="check_form_field fleft" align="right">
        <input type="image"  src="images/pay_now.jpg" name="payment" id="payment" value="Pay" alt="Pay">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

To combine the values dropdown boxes named month and year and combine them in the same form as a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to understand your question, and I'm not sure if it has any thing to do mysql.

It is combined as long as you have all the "input" under the same "form".

Hope that make sense.